# Sympy - unpredictable behavior of Solver

Tags: python, sympy

I am using the Sympy (version 0.7.3, Python 2.7.5, Mac OS X) solver to solve some matrix equations, and I encountered an inconsistent behavior which spoils my whole results. To be precise, the result seems to depend on the order of the equations that should be solved.

A minimum working example is produced by the following code:

```
from sympy import *
axx, bxx, byy = symbols('axx bxx byy')
```

This command

```
solve([axx - bxx, byy])
```

yields `{axx: bxx, byy: 0}` as result, whereas switching the order of the equations

```
solve([byy, axx - bxx])
```

gives `{byy: 0, bxx: axx}`, which of course mathematically is the same, but makes a difference when applying this solution using the SymPy `subs` function, i.e.:

```
axx.subs({byy: 0, bxx: axx})
```

returns `axx`, whereas

```
axx.subs({axx: bxx, byy: 0})
```

returns `bxx`, which can obviously cause a lot of trouble in later calculations.

I'd be grateful if someone could tell me how to make SymPy behave in a consistent way. I do not really care if the result is `{axx: bxx}` or `{bxx: axx}`, but it should be the same no matter in which order I pass in the equations.

Comment: There are additional arguments that you can provide to `solve` in order to specify with respect to what you want the solution. Check the examples in the docstring.

Comment: I already tried this, but if I include all symbols, i.e. `solve([axx - bxx, byy], [axx, bxx, byy])`, which I have to in my case, then the output is the same.

Comment: Why are you including all the symbols? Include the symbol that you want the equation solved for: `solve([x,y-z], [x,y])`

Comment: I have to, because I am interested in the interconnection between two tensors in a rather large set of linear equations.

Comment: There are a few other options you might have. Look at the keyword arguments that `solve` provides. There might be a way to exclude certain symbols from the final answer. Also, you might try to sort your input equations in some standard form, but this again might happen to rely on implementation details.

Answer (score 3):

As Krastanov noted, pass the second argument to solve, which tells it what symbols to solve for. For instance, if you want things in terms of the `b` variables, do

```
In [48]: solve([axx - bxx, byy], [bxx, byy])
Out[48]: {bxx: axx, byy: 0}

In [49]: solve([byy, axx - bxx], [bxx, byy])
Out[49]: {bxx: axx, byy: 0}
```

If you don't do this, it will just guess, and as you have found, the guess is arbitrary and may depend on things like the order of the equations or even the symbol names.

Comment: This solution does not work for me. Take for example:
`solve([bxx-axx, byy-axx])` which gives the desired result that `bxx = byy`. But letting Sympy solve `solve([bxx-axx, byy-axx], [bxx, byy])` only returns `{byy: axx, bxx: axx}`. It is a correct result, but unsuited for further processing.

In my more complicated case of equating two 3x3 matrices, telling SymPy what symbols to solve for leads to several relations staying undiscovered.

Comment: Can you give an example of a larger system with such undiscovered relations (maybe paste it to a gist or something)?

Answer (score -1):

Using the `manual=True` seems to solve my problem, although I have no idea why.

The [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html) says

> ‘manual=True (default is False)’
>
> do not use the polys/matrix method to solve a system of equations, solve them one at a time as you might “manually”.

whatever this should mean.

However, `solve([axx - bxx, byy], manual = True)` and `solve([axx - bxx, byy], manual = True)` both give the same result.

Comment: This is just a coincidence. In the future the algorithm can actually change and give a different answer.